# Version history not saving properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, document-set, versioning, version-history

I have 3 environments on which I have Versioning turned on. Each of them is created from the same PnP template, and has the same logicApps/etc connected to them. On one of them however, version history doesn't seem to save data from custom columns. For example:

In working scenario, when I update columns X,Y,Z, - Where X and Y are custom columns, and Z is OBB one, 3 of them will appear under "properties" tab in version history of document set.

In wrong scenario, with the same update - only Z column will appear in properties of version history, built in one. custom ones are not present in there.

Any ideas what is it about?

Comment: Do you reproduce this issue in other sites or other libraries/Document Sets? And how do you update these columns, manually or using other approaches? Per my test, Document Set version history captures and displays only the modified columns in the last record. But still, I’m not seeing this behavior from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was able to be reproduced on various environments. Whole document set content type and its columns were being installed via pipeline with PnP template.

It turned out, that on every environment, 2nd installation of PnP template fixed the issue. Why is that - any answers will be appreciated.